# Primary Key Needed on Fact Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, architecture, schema

I am currently developing a very complicated database schema and was wondering if the fact tables should have primary keys. Each fact table has 50+ columns of data and the only way to make a primary key would be to add an auto incrementing count to each tuple. I am just not sure what this information gets us in the long term, especially since the data will be deleted after 12 months.

My dimension tables of course will have primary keys, just wanting to know what is best practice.

Comment: Pinging Joe Celko :D Honestly, this is an extraordinarily broad *and* deep question if you want to get into the whys. The shortest reasonable answer possible is "Yes". Technically, of course "no" would be shorter. But that wouldn't be a reasonable answer.

Comment: @almhuran unfortunately the data is VERY sensitive and I can not give you any insights. I was just curious what other people have done in this situation

Comment: Haha, what I mean to say is that this kind of question can end up with discussions, debates, arguments, religious wars, Ragnarok, and is a bit broad for the site. So the only reasonable answer is just "yes you need a primary key". Exactly what form it should take in what scenario, and why, so on and so forth... well, there are gigagbytes of articles about that.

Comment: https://www.kimballgroup.com/2006/07/design-tip-81-fact-table-surrogate-key/

Comment: @almhuran Ah thats my fault! Thanks for the insight, I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always good to go for a clustering key, which will leads to easily seeking the data, when we need. Clustering key is not only used for clustered index queries. It is also being stored in every non-clustered index leaf page, for seeking back to the data pages, when there is key-lookup.

**Characteristics of good clustering key:**

- unique (no need for adding uniquefier to make value unique)
- incrementing (reduces fragmentation)
- narrow (less number of bytes to store in the tree pages of clustered index & in the leaf pages of non-clustered index)
- Static (reduces fragmentation)
- non-nullable (avoids null blocks)
- fixed width (avoids variable blocks)

[Read more on Kimberly Tripp Post on clustering key](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/)

Identity satisy all these clauses. They are good candidates for clustered index.
If you are going to hold data longer, you can go for `Bigint` and if you are going to hold for one year and purge, you can go for `int` datatype itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of putting an identity column on all tables.  This makes it easier to identify specific rows for updating and deleting.

On a fact table with lots of dimensions, of course, such a column can seem superfluous.  However, there is still usually a primary key -- which is the combination of dimensions.

I would encourage you to have a primary key on the table, either an identity column or a combination of existing rows.  If you use a composite primary key, you should be careful about the ordering of the keys.  SQL Server defaults to using the primary key as a clustered index, and if you put the keys in the wrong order, then your table is subject to fragmentation.  Identity keys don't have this issue.